# Getting current time of a different timezone using C++

Tags: c++, c, timezone

How do i get the current time of a different time zone? Example, i need to know the current time in Singapore where as my system is set to PT time.

Comment: See several answers for C at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73680872)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One implementation would be to use `time` to get the current time in UTC and then manipulate the `TZ` environment variable to your destination timezone. Then use `localtime_r` to convert to that timezone's local time.

Comment: Warning: It is unsafe to set an environment variable in a multi-threaded program (at least on POSIX). So you should only do this if your program is single-threaded.

Answer (score 12):

New answer for a very old question.

Given a C++11 or C++14 compiler, and [this timezone library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), the current time in Singapore is:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << date::make_zoned("Asia/Singapore", system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

which just output for me:

```
2015-08-19 05:25:05.453824 SGT
```

This gives the current local date, time and abbreviation in use.  And it is based off of the `<chrono>` library and the [IANA timezone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones).

`std::chrono::system_clock::now()` returns a time stamp in the UTC timezone.  This program locates the timezone information for "Asia/Singapore", and translates the UTC timestamp into a pair representing the local time and the current timezone for that location.

The above program is independent of the computer's current timezone.

### C++20 Update

In C++20 you can now do this (once your vendor ships it):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << zoned_time{"Asia/Singapore", system_clock::now()} << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2015-08-19 05:25:05.453824 SGT
```

Comment: zoned_time does not seem to be accepted by compilers yet :S

Comment: MSVC has shipped it.  gcc has implemented it on trunk but not yet shipped it.  LLVM has yet to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Use UTC (GMT) as much as possible.

If you need to (for example) print a report that's going to another time zone, use something like [SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724949%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to localise it.

Comment: This is simply not accurate. No such rules apply, because every job and every set of requirements are different. I can give you plenty of examples where you absolutely do not want to use UTC times. Teaching engineering is about helping people make the proper decisions, based on their situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert to GMT then convert to whatever time zone you want.

Comment: GMT is the way to go.  (I'm speaking at somebody in the US, so it isn't a matter of it being my time zone.)

Comment: How to handle day saving time(PDT/PST)?

Comment: You're going to have to provide quite a bit more context if you want a more specific answer. What's your operating system? Platform? Library set?

Answer (score 0):

### C++20 standart

List of timezones can find here - [www.zeitverschiebung.net](https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/)

String date format like `%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y`, here - [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)

If you need accuracy in seconds, etc, change minutes in `std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::minutes>` to the required value.

```
std::string date = std::format("{:%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y}",
                    std::chrono::zoned_time{ "Asia/Singapore",
                        std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::minutes>(
                            std::chrono::system_clock::now())
                    });
```

Also you can use std::vformat

```
std::string epoch2StrTZ(const time_t epoch, const std::string& date_format)
{
    std::string date = std::vformat("{:" + date_format + "}", std::make_format_args(
        std::chrono::zoned_time{ "Asia/Singapore",
            std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::minutes>(
                std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>(
                    std::chrono::seconds(epoch)
                )
            )
        }));

    return date;
}
```